# Consequences of returning response for HEAD request

Tags: http

Due to some decisions in the past, our custom proxy is unable to accept HEAD requests. Changing it to accept HEAD will be quite a lot of work. One approach was to use the code path used by GET when a HEAD request comes. But this would mean the response gets sent back as well. Is it ok to send back a response for a HEAD request? Or does it really depend on the upstream HTTP client? I feel the request body will anyway be ignored so shouldn't be a problem

Comment: That might cause issues.. Apart from the fact that you will greatly increase the size of the reply, which is _one_ possible motivation for HEAD requests you might in fact alter the way applications and APIs work behind your proxy: imagine a GET request triggering some action on the server side...

Comment: Let's assume the size is negligible [everything is under out control]. Also the API on which the HEAD request is done is just to get minor statistics. Let's just assume it is ok to convert HEAD to GET [nothing mentioned above is going to cause any problem in our case], I just want to know if it is ok to send a response or rather what will be the behaviour on the client side if a response comes along for a HEAD request [im talking more about how the underlying HTTP clients handle HEAD request with body] @arkascha

Comment: If "everything is under your control", then why do you ask? Then _you_ should be able to tell.

Comment: when I say everything is under my control I mean we are leveraging a HTTP client library. What will be its behavior when a response is returned for a HEAD request? @arkascha

Comment: Sorry, but that is even more confusing. You are leveraging a HTTP client library? Then especially you decide what that library does in such case.

Comment: ok i'll explain the overall architecture. we have a kibana server that hits our proxy. all this while things were good. we upgraded to newer version of kibana and now it does HEAD request to monitor elasticsearch [which is behind our proxy]. for this we are thinking of internally converting a HEAD to GET.

Comment: That would mean quite some load on the search engine, depending on the request. Not sure. Plus the additional payload to be generated for nothing each single time.

Comment: If that setup is just for that specific request, then the decision is yours, if it works for you, fine. I don't see any other requests coming into play then.

Comment: it's very less [it just returns few kbs of data and we are ok with that]